# Trying to avoid code duplication - virtual with template solution

Tags: c++, templates, virtual-functions

I have many objects which contain different properties.

I'm trying to create a properties' editor dialog where I can pass the properties as a template and then, based on the template, construct different dialog panels for representing that specific object properties.

Unfortunately, mixing the virtual functions and templates is not supported.

How can I pass the object properties and then return modified set back in order to modify the object visual representation?

One solution could be to send the object ID and construct the panels based on it with a long switch statement. But it seems ugly.

To make it more complicated, the dialog that will show with the properties and the objects are in different libraries. I'm trying to separate the code and break the linkage whenever possible.

```cpp
class A
{
private:
    std::string name, tag;
    font labelFont, textFont;
};

class B
{
private:
    std::string name, tag;
    color labelColor, textColor;
};

typedef template<type T> int CallDialog(window *parent, T &options, int objectType);

int CallDialog()
{
    MyDoalog dlg( parent, options, objectType );
    if( dlg.OK() )
    {
        if( objectType == 1 )
        {
            options.labelFont = dlg.GetLaelFont()
            options.textFnt = dlg.GetTextFont();
        }
    }
}
```

The function `CallDialog()` is in a different DLL (will be written by me), and I'm trying to avoid making multiple `CallDialog()`s passing all those properties depending on the object type.

Comment: Show your code, don't describe it in prose. Prepare a [mcve].

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, I don't have a code yet. Just merely trying to asses a good solution without doing code repetition...

Comment: Well, I for one am not sure what you mean by "properties", or by "pass the properties as a template". Show at least a sketch of what you envision the code that uses this machinery would look like. You seem to have a solution that involves code repetition or duplication - show an example of that.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, I just tried to put some pseudo-code of what  was talking about as possible solution.  It is pseudo-code as I'm not sure it will compile and I'm sure it is highly unoptimal.

Comment: How do `A` and `B` fit into this picture? Should there be instances of these classes in there somewhere? Do you expect their private members to be somehow set by `CallDialog`? What's the role of `int objectType`? What integer value is it expected to have, and how is `MyDialog` expected to interpret it?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, 1. Yes, there is a visual representation of the A and B. When the user right clicks on one of them - its properties object is populated and passed into the `CallDialog()`. 2. Yes - when the user presses OK. 3. `objectType` identifies whether I am using object of type A or type B. 4. Not sure about that, and the `MyDalog` is not doing any interpretation - its purpose is to allow user to edit the data if the user desires. The interpretation and settings will be done by caller.

Comment: So if the user changes labelText - the label wlll be updated for the object of class A on which the user pressed the right mouse button and invoked the dialog.

Comment: Think aboug `PropertyPageDialog from Win32/MFC applications.

Comment: Who's providing the "visual representation"? How does this piece know what `A` and `B` instances should visually look like? Do they derive from some common base class that implements the visual rendering? How is `MyDoalog` expected to know that it should present two strings and two fonts for `A`, but two strings and two colors for `B`? It is probably also expected to display some human-readable names for those properties (so the user knows which font and color is which) - where would those come from?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, 1. In the beginning the values are populated either from some default values or from saved  instance of the window.  3. No, they are not - A may be a surface and B may an object on the surface,,4.  was thinking that it would do so based either on the template class or `objectType`, but that's exactly the question..5. Yes. There are selectors for font and color and the different panels are already here. However the code needs to be written to select the different panels based on which object type we are talking about.

Comment: So, you already have some pre-defined piece of UI that collects two strings and two fonts, and another that collects two strings and two colors? And you just need to define a correspondence between `A` and `B` and those two UI pieces? To what extent do `A` and `B` expected to cooperate with this machinery? If nothing else, it's impossible to set private members of the class purely from outside, without some help from the class itself. Could `A` and `B` provide some kind of `SaveToOptions` and `PopulateFromOptions` methods?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, 1. Yes - this will initially be predefined. 2. Not correspondence between A and B - the are independent. I need a way to change properties of A and then properties of B independently and update A and/or B if the values changed. Remember - no connection between A and B exist. The are 2 independent types. 3. Yes -those 2 methods could be defined.

Comment: Now the question is - how to get the data pass to the actual dialog from the `CallDialog()`.  And use just the implementation of `CallDialog()`

Comment: You might define an `Options` object that contains  a union of everything on all the property sheets. `CallDialog` would call `T::SaveToOptions` (where `T` is the template parameter, bound to `A` or `B` or similar) to populate an instance of `Options`, then pass that instance to `MyDialog` that would in turn pass it to the appropriate property sheet (the ID of that sheet could also be stored in `Options`). The property sheet would update `Options` with new values when saved, and `CallDialog` would pass this updated object to `T::PopulateFromOptions`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, can you make some pseudo-code ni the answer? Thx

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, I think I got it. However, tring to make it - `typedef template<typename T> int (*CREATEPROPERTIESDIALOG)(window *parent, T& object);` fails to compile for the keyword `template``

Comment: What are you trying to declare? What is `CREATEPROPERTIESDIALOG` supposed to be? A function template? A template typedef aliasing a function pointer type?